# PHP preg_replace pattern only seems to work if its wrong?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like this

```
../Clean_Smarty_Projekt/tpl/templates_c\.
../Clean_Smarty_Projekt/tpl/templates_c\..
```

I want to replace `../`, `\.` and `\..` with a regulare expression.

Before, I did this like this:

```
$result = str_replace(array("../","\..","\."),"",$str);
```

And there it (pattern) has to be in this order because changing it makes the output a little buggy. So I decided to use a regular expression.

Now I came up with this pattern

```
$result = preg_replace('/(\.\.\/)|(\\[\.]{1,2})/',"",$str);
```

What actually returns only empty strings...

Reason: `(\\[\.]{1,2})`

In [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jB2xG5/1) its all ok. (Took me a couple of minutes to realize that I don't need the `/g` in preg_replace)

If I use this pattern in preg_replace I have to do `(\\\\[\.]{1,2})` to get it to work. But that's obviously wrong because im not searching for two slashes.

Of course I know the escaping rulse (escaping slashes).

Why doesn't this match correctly ?

Comment: yes, this works too but actually even 3 slashes is wrong because the slash is escaped and the follwed char has no escape.... 3 Slashes means I escape `[`  as well. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Dwza using 4 backslashes to match one backslash isn't "obviously wrong". It's in fact correct. When the php parser gets to 4 backslashes, it will interpret it as 2 backslashes. PHP will then pass it to the regex engine (2 backslashes) which is interpreted as 1 backslash. Side note: there's no need to escape the dot in a character class `[.]`: it loses its regex meaning inside it.

Comment: @HamZa phuu.. seems like playing "Chinese whisper" :D thx for this explanation.

Comment: @Dwza an answer regarding your recently closed question: http://codepad.viper-7.com/L0rXNR

Comment: @Steve thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for. Actually a combo between array_flip, dirname and array_filter. THX

Comment: @Dwza No problem, I really dont see what the problem with your question was either, but im glad i could help

Comment: @Steve same here. I want looking for a tool or some. I was looking for a better idea because my thougts of a function was more than 20 rows ^^ And I hadn't that filter and flip in mind. So actually i was looking for knowladge and found 90% haters ^^

Comment: Are you using this to clean up URL input from user/client? Doing it with your current regex is a totally bad idea from security's perspective. https://regex101.com/r/jB2xG5/2. Example input `../Clean_Smarty_Projekt/tpl/....//templates_c\\....`

Comment: @nhahtdh No, actually i'm just using this to clear the structure of a filepath because i builded a ziipper-class and there i need clean pathes to add the files from source to target :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use a different php delimiter. Within the `/` delimiter, you need to use three `\\\` or four `\\\\` backslashes to match a single backslash.

```
$string = '../Clean_Smarty_Projekt/tpl/templates_c\.'."\n".'../Clean_Smarty_Projekt/tpl/templates_c\..';
echo preg_replace('~\.\./|\\\.{1,2}~', '', $string)
```

Output:

```
Clean_Smarty_Projekt/tpl/templates_c
Clean_Smarty_Projekt/tpl/templates_c
```

Comment: It'd be best to group both matches, on the basis that your `|` is ambiguous, so your pattern will replace _"../.."_ as being one match (_".."_ + `[/\/]` <-- the or applied to a single char, and then _".."_ literals, too). That might be an issue in a string like _"foo..\../bar"_, where it will not behave as expected